# Does access token become invalid or not after revoking permissions?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using Google **OAuth 2.0** in my application. I have a refresh token which I use to get access token whenever my access token expires. I don't fetch a new refresh token unless I get an error 400 while fetching my access token which usually means my refresh token is not valid anymore(user has revoked permissions to my app).

Now after revoking permissions to my app, I tried to call API which uses the access token(which is not expired yet) are working fine. I know when this token expires I wont be able to fetch new one unless I fetch a new refresh token.

But I thought on revoking permissions, both refresh token and access token become invalid?? Yes??Then, how my access token is still working??

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate exactly how you are revoking the permissions?

Comment: From here:https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security?target=permissions#connectedapps

Answer (score 0):

Access token is sent to the resource server, which can only check that the access token is valid and not expired.
When you revoke permissions to the client app, you do it in the authorization server, and the client app can continue accessing the resource server until the access token is expired and need to refresh it, and then will receive a 401 - Unauthorized response.
That's why it is recommended to define a short access token expiry time span.